# How to include a command line parameter when making a setup.exe with Installshield

Tags: logging, command-line, windows-installer, installshield, installscript

I'm building an installscript MSI project with InstallShield 2014 professional.
I'm trying to create a log file of the installation. 
I've set the "Create MSI Logs" property to voicewarmup, and a log file is created in a random location in %temp%.
What I need though is to create the log file with a specific name in a specific location. With a basic MSI project you could just specify a location and prompt the user at the end of an installation to chose to view it. I don't have the same option with the installscript msi project.
I did manage to copy the log file to a specific location+name when running the setup.exe file via cmd:
setup.exe /verbose "filelocation\logname.log".
Is there a way to have installshiled build the setup.exe file with the commandline parameters "built in"? when I try to add the command to "MSI command-line arguments" in the "release" tab, it sends the command only when the .exe runs the .msi, and then I get an error saying the command is invalid.

Also if there's a way to create a log file for the user to pick after installation is complete (like in the basic MSI project) - I'd love to hear.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

In the release definition, you have a setup.exe tab.
The first line "MSI Command Line arguments" you can hardcode the location and name of the logfile that needs to be created during every setup run.

```
E.g /L*v %windir%\temp\logfile.log
```

Hope this helps